# A positive square integrable random variable whit non square integrable inverse

Tags: real-analysis, probability, random-variables, examples-counterexamples

I'm looking for an example of a Square Integrable Random Variable, whose [multiplicative inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_inverse) is **not** Square Integrable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about an exponential random variable? (Or any other positive square-integrable random variable with a density function that is bounded away from $0$ in a neighborhood of $0$.)

**More detail:** Let $X$ be a positive random variable with $\Bbb E[X^2]<\infty$ and density $f_X$ such that $f_X(x)\ge\delta>$ for $0<x<x_0$. (An exponential random variable is a specific example.) Then
$$
\eqalign{
\Bbb E[X^{-2}]
&=\int_0^\infty x^{-2} f_X(x)\,dx
=\int_0^\infty f_X(t^{-1})\,dt\cr
&\ge\int_{1/x_0}^\infty f_X(t^{-1})\,dt
\ge\int_{1/x_0}^\infty \delta\,dt=\infty.\cr
}
$$

Comment: Why the boundedness in a neighborhood of 0 is needed ? My feeling would say it has something to do with the characteristic function, correct?

Comment: @J.C.: I've added more detail t my answer.